# IOS UIScrollView: Cannot scroll until the end of the content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to generate a scroll controller in a window with the UIScrollView class, which will contain numerous UIButtons, placed vertically. I set the size of the scroll view equal to the current view controller's root view, so that the scroll view covers the entire visible window. Then I generate the UIButtons I am going to add to the scroll view: I add each UIButton just in the below of the previous UIButton and I add the height of the current UIButton to a variable called "totalContentHeight". Finally, I set the height of the contentSize of the scroll view to this value, in the following line of code:

```
self.scrollViewForNewsButtons.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, totalContentHeight);
```

totalContentHeight is equal to numOfButtons*eachButtonsHeight after I add all the buttons to the scroll view.

The problem is, in the simulator, when I run the app and scroll until the end of the last button and release the mouse, the last two buttons bounces back such that they lie outside of the visible window. It is somewhat hard to express with mere words, so here are the images:

1)This is what I get when I scrolled until the end of the content and held the content at the last possible position it could be pushed:

[image: scrolled pic]

2)This is what I get after I released the mouse and the scroll view bounced back to its final position:

[image: not scrolled pic]

As you can see, the last two buttons are drawn outside of the visible area. It is like the scroll view's area covers the whole window plus the button area of the IPhone. I could not find a reasonable explanation for this. Am I setting the area size wrong or am I missing something else?

Comment: I don't know why, but looks like you have 2 status bars up there. Maybe this messes up the scroll view size or position.

Comment: That second status bar with "Turkcell 3G" etc is just a part of the background image, it is not an actual status bar.

Comment: I suggest you show us the code where you set the size of the scrollview.

Comment: what is the height of scroleview?

Comment: Use contentSize.height = CGRectGetMaxY(lastButton.frame);

Comment: `self.scrollViewForNewsButtons = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, offset, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - offset)];` This is the code I where I set the scroll view size. offset is a small value(20), with it I wanted to leave room for the status bar. But I subtract the same value from the root view height to compensate the offset at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just set content size with calculation with your total button and its height...For Ex..

```
float yheight = totalButton * yourButtonHeight;
[yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, yheight + 44)];
```

try this code...

Comment: @UfukCanBicici i think this happen because in scrollview and textview here frame calculate with navigationcontroller and also tabbarcontroller so i think this happen try to add my code...

Comment: This works, I solved it this way already, but adding a constant to the total height doesn't seem to be a robust solution for me, since I will need many such scroll views in this app. How can I get this small offset (44 in your code) programatically instead of finding it with trial-errors?

Comment: @UfukCanBiçici i set many controls some code is    

    
    float ftbl = txtantenimities.frame.origin.y + txtantenimities.contentSize.height + 15;
    
    tblbackview.frame=CGRectMake(tblbackview.frame.origin.x, ftbl, tblbackview.frame.size.width, tblbackview.frame.size.height);
    
    float fscrview = tblbackview.frame.origin.y + tblbackview.frame.size.height + 20;
    scrview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, fscrview);

Comment: @UfukCanBiçici see just take yourButton1.frame.origin.y + your total height dude...

Comment: @UfukCanBiçici and its why because here tabbar is there but its hidden.. try to show that and then check its also hide with it so in xib just display the tabbar and then put scrollview after hide the tabbar also.. try something change see dude.. :)

Comment: Yes, It is working now, I added the following code just to be sure about the navigation bar: `float navBarHeight = 2 * [[self.navigationController navigationBar] frame].size.height;
    
    self.scrollViewForNewsButtons.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, totalContentHeight + navBarHeight);`

It seems the navBar really takes 44 pixels, I printf'd its height :). But it only works if I multiply the height by two and it exactly covers the last button. It looks like there are "two" navigation bars. I only use a single navigation controller; so from where does the other bar come?

Comment: dude.... here also may be problem with UITabBarController same as dude.. but see somewhere its also do some pro when u use textview and also scrollview..

Comment: Well, I only use a UINavigationController and in this view controller, there is only a single UIScrollView and nothing else. I still don't see the source of the other 44 pixels. Moreover, why would the navbar interfere with how the scroll view handles its local subviews; I mean, the navigationBar and the scroll view lie in different view hierarchies?

Comment: i also think about it and its possible but why?? i dont know dude... :( but its a problem with view and scrollview,textview

Answer (score 0):

And if you set the scrollview frame size the same as

```
self.view.bounds
```

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the self.view.frame to self.view.bounds results the same.